# CSS Positioning in multiple tables

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of controls that are rendered one per line (like a repeater).
Each control renders its own table.
So the output looks like this:

```
<div>
    <table><tr><td>Product1</td><td>Produce1 Description 1</td></tr></table>
    <table><tr><td>Product1</td><td>Produce1 Description 1</td></tr></table>
    <table><tr><td>Product1</td><td>Produce1 Description 1</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

The problem is that I get results that look like this:

```
Shoes      Shoes Description
Black T-Shirt      Black Medium Sized T-Shirt
Green Jeans    Green Medium sized Jeans
```

I need to make the first and the second table cell be the same size on each rendered control.Is it possible to do this without hardcoding explicit pixel amounts (since the window can be resized)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution which worked in my case:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">         
    .FirstColumn    
        { 
            width: 40%; 
            display:inline-block;
        }
    .SecondColumn    
        {
            width: 60%; 
            display:inline-block;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">     
        <div style="width:100%">
            <div style="width:100%">
                <span class="FirstColumn">Some long product name.</span><span class="SecondColumn">Product 1 Descriptione.</span>
            </div>
            <div style="width:100%">
                <span class="FirstColumn">Product name.</span><span class="SecondColumn">Product 1 Long Descriptione.</span>
            </div>
            <div style="width:100%">
                <span class="FirstColumn">Product.</span><span class="SecondColumn">Product 1 Suprt Long Descriptione.</span>
            </div>
        </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sure that'll work, assuming that you'll always have exactly two columns in all of your tables...

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a separate table for each row. Merge them into one big table, the rows will still be rendered incrementally as long as you make sure to close them properly. Something like:

```
<div>
    <table>
    <tr><td>Product1</td><td>Produce1 Description 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Product1</td><td>Produce1 Description 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Product1</td><td>Produce1 Description 1</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Another way to do this (perhaps a bit neater) is to use **CSS** tables:

```
<div class = "tablecontainer">
    <div class = "rowcontainer"><div class = "cell">Product 1</div><div class = "cell">Product 1 Description</div></div>
     <div class = "rowcontainer"><div class = "cell">Product 2</div><div class = "cell">Product 2 Description</div></div>
    <div class = "rowcontainer"><div class = "cell">Product 3</div><div class = "cell">Product 3 Description</div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tablecontainer {
    display: table;
}
.rowcontainer {
    display: table-row;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

I hope that helped!

Comment: I am not sure it is a good idea to have a control just render <TR> and <TD> without a <TABLE>. Then the user always has to remember to put the control inside a <TABLE> tag.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to response, I had to finish other stuff, but this second example does not make all the cells in the same column the same width.